Different variants of Brahmasambandha vow in Pushti Marga
There's an excellent answer provided by Keshav Srinivasan. However, the same mantra was featured in the movie "Maharaj" as the true Brahmasambandha vow.
tasmad datu svop bhoge purvameva sarvastu padenbharya
putradinaam aapi samarpanam karyam
vivaahnantaram svopbhoge sarvam karye sarvam karyam nimit
tat karyo upbhogi vasto samarpanam karyam samarapanam krutva
paschatani tani karyani kartavya nitya artha

तस्माद् दत्तुं स्वोपभोगे पूर्वमेव सर्वस्वं पत्ये नित्यं पूत्रादीनामपि समर्पणं कार्यं।
विवाहानन्तरं स्वोपभोगे सर्वं कार्यं सर्वं कार्यं निमित्तं तत् कार्यो उपभोगी वस्तु समर्पणं कार्यं समर्पणं कृत्वा।
पश्चात् तानि तानि कार्याणि कर्तव्यानि नित्यार्थम्।

Can someone please verify the accuracy of this mantra with respect to the Brahmasambandha vow?
